# MyAnnotation title problem

Tags: iphone

How can I get a Multiple Line Address in an MKAnnotation title?
For example:

```
MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
ann.title = @"abcdefjkskfjhsjkdhfsjdhfjkshdkfjskjfkjshdf ";
```

MyAnnotation is my NSObject class which set the title.

But the bubble only displays one line and another subtitle, so how can I get the whole
text in multiple lines?

Answer (score 0):

What I read that isn't easy. You have to customize the Callout bubble. This answer isn't a real solution, but a hint how it could be made if it's worthwhile.

https://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/01/1283370619995.html

http://www.jakeri.net/2009/12/custom-callout-bubble-in-mkmapview-final-solution/

http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=81

More on this topic:

> [How to customize the callout bubble for MKAnnotationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview)
>
> [How to add a combobox and a button to the infoWindow on Google map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176467/how-to-add-a-combobox-and-a-button-to-the-infowindow-on-google-map)
>
> [How to add more details in MKAnnotation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-iphone-os)
>   (iCodeBlogAnnoationView.m and WeatherAnnotationView.m)