# Custom callout view for MKAnnotation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkannotation, mkannotationview

The standard callout, a black bubble, is nice, but can this be customized? For instance I would like to make a white bubble version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customizing the MKAnnotation Callout bubble](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094325/customizing-the-mkannotation-callout-bubble)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a great answer to this problem here: [Customizing the MKAnnotation Callout bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094325/customizing-the-mkannotation-callout-bubble)

Where this answer is given by @MathieuF:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation{   
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];

// Button
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 23, 23);
annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = button;

// Image and two labels
UIView *leftCAV = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,23,23)];
[leftCAV addSubview : yourImageView];
[leftCAV addSubview : yourFirstLabel];
[leftCAV addSubview : yourSecondLabel];
annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = leftCAV;

annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;

return pin;
}
```

Comment: That's great, but it doesn't deal with the triangle that comes down from the bubble, or variable width bubbles (to contain variable amounts of text)

Comment: @cannyboy same problem here. Can you please let me know how did you solved it??

Comment: i need two Buttons one on leftView & rightView ? 
how to add Custom Button with action to the Left View and rightView ?