# How can i change mapkit annotation detail view background color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, annotations, mkmapview

Hi am trying to change the annotation detail view(show in map image) into a custom design like the second image.

How can i change that background image and all?

my current code is

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation {

    mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
    if([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;


    static NSString *identifier = @"myAnnotation";
    MKPinAnnotationView * annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView*)[_MAPVIEW dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (!annotationView)
    {

        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        annotationView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorPurple;

        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
    }else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    UIButton *infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];


    [infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetailView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = infoButton;

    UIImageView *imageV=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin.png"]];
    annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView=imageV;
    return annotationView;
}
```

current annotation detail view design(when i click on pin then i can see the annotation detail view )

[image]

but i want something like this design

[image]

please help  me.

Comment: You will have to build that yourself, since iOS7 the standard view has changed to the white one.

Comment: is there any tutorial for that?

Comment: Take a look at this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094325/customizing-the-mkannotation-callout-bubble/4094956#4094956