# How to increase the callout size in maps in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

can anyone suggest me how to increase the callout size in maps.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview

Comment: Yeah I tried it but I am not successful.any other ideas??

Comment: If you are not successful - post the specific problem(s) you are encountering.