# MKMapview annotations

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I would like to customize the annotations into multiple line of subtitle.
The callouts shows name, date, time, title, addresses, image and button.

Is a way to do this customization in the mapview?

Thanks in adv

Comment: Plenty of similar questions on SO, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. You have to do almost everything by code. You can also create you own views with Interface Builder, but that still requires a nice amount of code to work.