# Emulate Apple's custom map annotation callout in Photos app

Tags: ios, ipad, mkmapview, mapkit, callout

In Apple's built in Photos app on the iPad, if you select the Places tab you'll see a map with pins (annotations) showing where you took photos.

If you select a pin, instead of the standard, text callout bubble you get a nice thumbnail of the photo (s) taken at that location.

I have Googled this to death but cannot find a solution which allows us to create custom callouts like this. Has anyone got any ideas?

[image: iPad Phtos App]

Comment: Take a look at [customize callout bubble for annotation view?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565828/643383) for help with this.

Comment: You can refer to this project for a quick demo. https://github.com/akshay1188/CustomAnnotation for customizing annotations