# How to set two liner text when display the PIN info

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, maps, mapkit

I am creating iPhone application where I am showing my office location and its working perfectly.

For map I followed [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/).

On link, I have code as below.

```
DisplayMap *ann = [[DisplayMap alloc] init]; 
ann.title = @" Kolkata";
ann.subtitle = @"Mahatma Gandhi Road";
```

What I want is subtitle as below.

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

How could I do the same?

Any idea or suggestions please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/how-to-customize-the-callout-bubble-for-mkannotationview/1769862#1769862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default style of map only supports the title and subtitle.

You cannot use multiple subtitles for a pin annotation.

Please review the [sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html) provided by Apple.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please take a look at my another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13403977/set-link-color-to-black-in-ios). I am newbie for iOS development