# set Link color to black in iOS

Tags: ios, ios5, colors, hyperlink

I am newbie for iOS development (though I am web developer since last 2 years)

I have created a link on my screen using TextView and provided color as black. However when I run my application I see link color as BLUE. Any idea how to make link color to BLACK?

Is there anything like CSS for iOS development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily format text within `UIWebView`, something like below:

```
        NSString *pureHtmlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><STYLE 
type=text/css>body{margin-top:1cm;}</STYLE></head><body style=background-color: 
transparent;><br /><p><font face=heveltica neue; size=5>Other text: </font></p></body></html>"];


    //Load text in UIWebView (don't forget to declare a UIWebView instance for sure)
    [webView loadHTMLString:pureHtmlText baseURL:nil];
```

For more details, i recommend you the official [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) documentations.

**EDIT:**

@Fahim Parker:

Yahoo link will not gets called because `baseURL` is set to `nil`, you have better option: create a html file, `myFile.html`, include it into your Xcode project, and change your code to something like:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *path = [myBundle pathForResource:@"myFile" ofType:@"html"];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[self.webView loadHTMLString:@"myFile.html" baseURL:baseURL];
```

Comment: I am using code as `NSString *pureHtmlText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><a href=www.yahoo.com>Click Me</a></body></html>` When I click on Click Me, yahoo doesn't get open in browser? Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic recognition links in `UITextView` always show up blue, unless you subclass and customize it. You can use `UIWebView` to display some styled HTML content though.

Comment: any example how could I use UIWebView in this case?

Comment: Load an HTML into it, what else do you need?