# multiple annotation in map messing

Tags: iphone, ios, dictionary

[image]I have dot as a pin annotation in map and showing custom annotation view.My problem is that when I click on dot sometimes dot behinds custom annotation view comes in fron of custom annotation view instead of showing behind it.

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{ 
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView;
    PinAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    NSString *identifier;
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]]) 
    {
        identifier = @"Pin";
        NSInteger myid = ((DisplayMap *)annotation).takeid;
        MKAnnotationView *pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        DisplayMap *a = (DisplayMap *)annotation;
        pinView.annotation=a;
        if (myid == 1) 
        {
           UIImage *test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red_dot.png"];
           pinView.image = test;
           pinView.opaque = NO;
       }
       else if (myid == 2)
       {
           UIImage *test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_dot.png"];
           pinView.image = test;
           pinView.opaque = NO;
       }
       else {
           UIImage *test = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green_dot.png"];
           pinView.image = test;
           pinView.opaque = NO;
       }
    return pinView;
  }
  else if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[CalloutAnnotation class]])
  {
       identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Callout%d",pinView.tag];
       annotationView = [[CalloutAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
       CalloutAnnotation *calloutAnnotation = (CalloutAnnotation *)annotation;
       ((CalloutAnnotationView *)annotationView).title = calloutAnnotation.title;
       ((CalloutAnnotationView *)annotationView).iTag = calloutAnnotation.iTag;
       [annotationView setNeedsDisplay];
       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
                     animations:^(void) {
                         mapView.centerCoordinate = calloutAnnotation.coordinate;
                     }];
       annotationView.annotation = annotation;
       return annotationView;
  }
}


-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view1
{
    if ([view1.annotation isKindOfClass:[DisplayMap class]])
    {
    DisplayMap *pinAnnotation = ((DisplayMap *)view1.annotation);
    LoginDetail *obj =    [[appDelegate mapArray] objectAtIndex:pinAnnotation.iTag];
    [mapView removeAnnotations:annotationRemoveArray];

    CalloutAnnotation *calloutAnnotation = [[CalloutAnnotation alloc] init];
    calloutAnnotation.title      = pinAnnotation.title;
    pinAnnotation.calloutAnnotation = calloutAnnotation;
    [mapView addAnnotation:calloutAnnotation];
    [annotationRemoveArray addObject:calloutAnnotation];
    [self setzoomonselectannotation:pinAnnotation.coordinate];
    }
}
```

Comment: please improve the question

Comment: try removing all other annotation and showing only the current

Comment: @Rushabh now can u help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callout window is an annotation view as well. That is wrong ;)

follow one the hints:
[How to customize the callout bubble for MKAnnotationView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/how-to-customize-the-callout-bubble-for-mkannotationview)

Basically what they say: make the callout a subview of the pin itself