# How to add a combobox and a button to the infoWindow on Google map?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps

Currently, I'm developing an application, in which I have to show an infoWindow on click event on map itself.

My question is I want to show a button as well as a combobox on this infoWindow. 
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a custom *UIView* to your *MKMapView* and supress the default *MKAnnotation* callout view. Your custom *UIView* can include the controls you want in the callout.

You might find the following useful:

- [customize callout bubble for annotationview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565828/customize-callout-bubble-for-annotationview)
- [A development blog with some posts on customizing MKMapView.](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?cat=4)

I don't think either of these posts describe a definitive, clean solution to your problem (scrolling problem with the subview position).  I suggest you re-think your UI and consider pushing an entirely new view from the standard callout right disclosure button.  I feel like customizing the callout (*infoWindow* equivalent) doesn't translate well to the iPhone platform.

**Edit**:

Ok.  So all you want to know is how to show a check box in an infoWindow using the [regular Google Maps Javascript API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html)?

That is a much easier question.  If you have a look at the [GMarker openInfoWindow](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMarker), you will find that the first paramter to this method is a string.  This string needs to be populated with the HTML that you would like in your *infoWindow*. So for your checkbox and button you need an *input* element of type *checkbox* and *button*:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane" />
<input type="button" value="Blah" />
```

Comment: Cannonade, basically I'm using HTML and javascripts to develop this app. So I'm not using MKAnnotation, mapView etc. So there's no callout view here. I've to use infoWindow only.

Comment: I tried this. My snippet goes as 

map.openInfoWindow(myGeographicCoordinates,<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane" />);

myGeographicCoordinates are the touch locations I'm detecting.


How am I suppose to render the information in these tags? Single quotes, double quotes, will only have this statement as a string. And assigning this string to a variable again will take this as a string. Thanx in advance.

Comment: You need to escape the quotes with a backslash.

map.openInfoWindow(myGeographicCoordinates,"<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"vehicle\" value=\"Airplane\" />");

Comment: @neha very glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the content attribute of InfoWindow itself?

```
myWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content:'<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Airplane" /><input type="button" value="Blah" />',
});

myWindow.open(map, marker);
```