# How to add more details in MKAnnotation in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkannotation

I want to add more details in MKAnnotation like location title, description, date, location name. So it will be four lines that are needed. But I found that only 2 parameters can be passed to MKAnnotation which are title and subtitle. How can I add more details on the map? Plz help me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: i tried by adding the details appending to subtitle.. But it showed in one line.. How i can show details in multiple lines

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at creating a custom `MKAnnotationView` object... it is basically a `UIView` that is tailored for map annotations.  In that object you could have your 4 custom labels.

In your `MKMapViewDelegate` class, you implement the `viewForAnnotation` method:

```
- (CustomMapAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    CustomMapAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;

    // determine the type of annotation, and produce the correct type of annotation view for it.
    CustomMapAnnotation* myAnnotation = (CustomMapAnnotation *)annotation;

    NSString* identifier = @"CustomMapAnnotation";
    CustomMapAnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (CustomMapAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if(nil == newAnnotationView) {
        newAnnotationView = [[[CustomMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:myAnnotation reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }

    annotationView = newAnnotationView;
    [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
    [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

    return annotationView;
}
```

And that will display your custom view where ever you have an annotation...  if you want a step by step tutorial, [check out this video](http://icodeblog.com/2009/12/21/introduction-to-mapkit-in-iphone-os-3-0/).

hope this helps

**EDIT**

I actually just found a new [Maps example](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/WeatherMap/index.html) on the apple dev site... has all the source code you need to go through.  They are also using a custom `MKAnnotationView` called `WeatherAnnotationView`

Comment: thank u for ur answer. Can i add the details into the default bubble  in wanted format , like with newline ? I tried by addding UIlabel to rightCalloutAccessoryView of   MKPinAnnotationView. But its not lloking nice.thanks in advance

Comment: I wouldn't try to do it the way you are trying to do it... Apple has setup annotations so they can be extended with the MKAnnotationView class.  Trying to override the rightCalloutAccessoryView in the way you are doing it is not a good way to do it... you are fighting the framework and it is giving you weird results.  If you want a custom annotation, the best way to do it is the way I described.

Comment: the tutorial only changes the annotation image.. that's pretty much a one-liner

Comment: Is there an answer for this in swift?

Comment: @S.P. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831382/how-to-display-2-lines-of-text-for-subtitle-of-mkannotation-and-change-the-image