# How to show more text on annotation view

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have created an iPhone app which loads the map using the `MKMapkit`. When clicking on the map, it shows `MKAnnotation` with title and subtitle strings.

Now I want to know how I can show the annotation with multiple lines of text. Please show me how to do it. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Please edit the title so that it is more descriptive of the actual problem.  This will make it easier to search for later (for anyone else who has this question in the future)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MapCallOuts](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MapCallouts/Introduction/Intro.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009746) demo from Apple.

Comment: @WrightCS : i checked it..but I want to show more text..is that possible?

Comment: @barbgal check out this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-iphone-os/2342701#2342701

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i check the given link.I have doubt in CustomMapAnnotationView class. do i need to create this class by subclassing uiview? am i right? pls help me up

Comment: @WrightCs : I am stuck with the implementation, can you show me some working code since i am new for iphone dev.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to sublass the annotation view and make your own callout see this example [How to add more details in MKAnnotation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-ios) this may also help source provided https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/index.html