# custom MKAnnotationView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been trying to create a MKAnnotationView which has to display multiple line of text.

Some one has pointed me to do things said in the below url

[How to add more details in MKAnnotation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-iphone-os/2342701#2342701)

But i am not sure how to attain it due to my small knowledge in iPhone programming..

i have searched for a long tme but no use ...

Looking for help...Please guide me ..

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify, and based on what you are saying, you want to customise the look of the CALLOUT bubble that shows title/subtitle, not the annotation view itself, is this correct?

In case you're not clear, the MKAnnotationView is basically the image/icon/button that you see on top of the map for a specific location. Once you tap on that image/icon, if enabled, a call out bubble will appear where you can set a view for the left hand side, title, subtitle and a view for the right hand side - is this what you are hoping to customise?

If that's the case, this is a non-trivial task and if you are new to iPhone development chances are this is going to take a long time for you to implement.

If you still want to have a look, here's a blog post that might be of interest to you... http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/akshay1188/CustomAnnotation) is another demonstration of customizing the callout bubble of an MKAnnotationView.