# How to Increase height of annotation Title and subTitle area?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add more details in MKAnnotation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-ios)

Any buddies knows how to increase height of annotation title and subtitle field in mkannotation view.

Comment: Have you tried googling before asking question, SO is not personal search assistant.

Comment: Another one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831382/how-to-display-2-lines-of-text-for-subtitle-of-mkannotation-and-change-the-image

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WeatherMap/Introduction/Intro.html check this example..  Ref : [How to add more details in MKAnnotation in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-ios/2342701#2342701)