# Customize MapKit MKAnnotation Callout bubble to display a multiline text in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit, mapkitannotation

In IOS I have a map with several MKAnnotation, 
Clicking on one of them I see the bubble with a text, 
but the text is too long, then it is not displayed in its entirety.

I'm looking for a way to display text in a multiline TextView, or something similar, so that it is fully displayed.

Comment: plz see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5831382/how-to-display-2-lines-of-text-for-subtitle-of-mkannotation-and-change-the-image

Answer (score 1):

iOS 9.0 onwards you can use detailCalloutAccessoryView. You can add your textView in there. Here is the documentation link - https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkannotationview?language=objc