# Autosize annotation.title

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mkmapview

How can I autosize the annotation.title or subtitle?

[image]

Comment: you have to manage custom annotation for it. This may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30793315/customize-mkannotation-callout-view/30795086#30795086

Comment: Sorry, but i don't know Obj-C, it's hard for me, beacause i'm novice in swift and in programming. Swift my first language

Comment: Then get help from here to convert from objective c to swift. https://objectivec2swift.com.

Comment: @YagneshDobariya oh, i don't know about this objectivec2swift.com., thanks. I will use

Comment: Swift version here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40214778/how-to-show-multiple-lines-in-mkannotation-with-autolayout