# How to create custom annotation and callout in iphone

Tags: xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to create a custom annotation and callout on MKMapView. I have to create annotations with bigger in size and have to display three or four lines of text(labels). So how to create a custom annotation and callout bubble.

Thanks in advance.

Ashish

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: I have used a technique similar to the one used in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reimplement just 3 methods:

to customise your annotation use:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id)annotation
```

here just add subview which you need

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

here just delete your custom callOutView from superView

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didDeselectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
```

Check this [blog](http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-custom-callout/) for details

Answer (score -2):

You can use this.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)newMapView viewForAnnotation:(id )newAnnotation {
    MKAnnotationView *a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:newAnnotation reuseIdentifier:@"PinView"];

    if ( a == nil )
        a = [ [ MKAnnotationView alloc ] initWithAnnotation:newAnnotation reuseIdentifier: @"PinView" ];

    a.image = [ UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png" ];
    a.canShowCallout = YES;
    a.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure ];
    UIImageView *imgView = [ [ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:[ UIImage imageNamed:@"Image.png" ] ];
    a.leftCalloutAccessoryView = imgView;

    return a;
}
```