# MapAnnotations iOS 7+

Tags: ios, objective-c

Are there any other fields that can be added to a MapAnnotation other than setTitle and setSubtitle? I want to add more information to it than just 2 bits of data.

### EDIT

I am looking for iOS 7+ info on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342070/how-to-add-more-details-in-mkannotation-in-ios

Comment: Problem is the link to the tutorial is broken and it's not for iOS 7.

Comment: I think that duplicate link by foggzilla confuses the MKAnnotation protocol which is a template for your _model_ class with the MKAnnotationView which is the _view_ for your model class.  The accepted answer here is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MKAnnotation` is a protocol, so you can make any class into an annotation by making it conform to that protocol. As long as that class fulfils the requirements (`title`, `subtitle` and `coordinate`) you can add whatever properties you want. None of this has changed in iOS 7.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Shop : NSObject <MKAnnotation, NSCoding>

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

@property (nonatomic, assign) int shopId;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *shopOwnerName;

@end
```